# how to avoid UIView touch gestures overlapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UIView on top of another view that's using a UITouchGesture. The problem is that the touch events are being recognised in most forward UIView as well as in the UIView in the background. I would like the touch events to only work on the back most view only.

hope that makes sense.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I can see to you to do that is you declare the UITouchGesture in your views, and when you need to disable the touch in the view you can disable:

An example for a tap:

In your .h file you declare it:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tap;
```

And in your .m file

```
tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[yourView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And when you need to disable the tap you can simple:

```
[tap setEnable:NO];
```

or remove it:

```
[yourView removeGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

With that when you need to enable/disable will be easier and also will be easier to you to manage your touchs.

[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

view being the most forward UIview.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks! what if I want to put a UIButton is that most forward view? the userInteractionEnabled = NO would be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check if the `[gesture view]` is equal to `[[self.view subviews] objectAtIndex:0]` and perform any action.